# u8g2 arm library - using SDL output and keyboard input for GPIO simulation on desktop

Tags: linux, sdl, emulation, gpio

I'm using [u8g2arm-example](https://github.com/antiprism/libu8g2arm/tree/main/examples) SDL output on my ubuntu desktop to debug and develop a display application that later shall run on my raspberry pi using a small display using this library.

The SDL output function from the last example in the above link gives the chance to do the display output via SDL on my linux dekstop. The library also has features of implementing a menu with up/down/left/right buttons [u8g2-begin() function](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/u8g2reference#begin). You construct the display then with:

```
bool U8G2::begin(uint8_t menu_select_pin, uint8_t menu_next_pin, uint8_t menu_prev_pin, uint8_t menu_up_pin = U8X8_PIN_NONE, uint8_t menu_down_pin = U8X8_PIN_NONE, uint8_t menu_home_pin = U8X8_PIN_NONE)
```

Is it somehow possible to also map those GPIO pins to key-events of my desktop machine?
Then I would have a real simulation environment to develop with `u8g2`.